# Files and Code disappear and don't show up

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to open source code I downloaded but I can't find the code because it keeps disappearing. I will provide screenshots of what keeps happening.
[First few seconds after I open the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp7km.png)
[And then it becomes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMD71.png)
[The file contains these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0srjo.png)
[And the actual code is in these classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2YQv.png)
[When I try to open a class, the code appears for a split second but then it goes away and it becomes like the second picture I gave.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh6Io.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: No, there aren't any errors.

Comment: Is it possible to share project and idea.log?

Comment: Try moving the project outside of the cloud sync managed folder and open it from there. Make sure it's on the local disk.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, that solved the problem